# How to download jcenter.bintray entire repository or

Tags: android, maven, offline, bintray, jcenter

I want to download all the repositories that are necessary to work with android studio offline. What the official documentation says does not work at all well, since, at least once you need internet, and each time you add a new library too. I already have the google maven, but I see that not all packages are there. Although we are in 2020, the availability of the internet where I live is not very good, and it is expensive. What do I need to download to really work offline? Is there a way to download the jcenter? Cheers

Comment: Gradle and Maven do cache the libraries locally at first time you build your project after you added the dependency. so next time it will be picked from local cache. Downloading entire JCenter is not practical since it require multiple terabytes space required.

Comment: I know that, but if I have to add a new library I need internet, so I want to download jcenter for avoid internet...

Comment: Everytime you need a new release which has been release before the last download you have to have a connection otherwise you can not get the new version... and if you use jcenter or central does not matter.

Comment: Adding the "whole" JCenter is not practical as it is probably TB of storage. You can try to "guess" what packages you need, but that is also not practical. I am sorry mate, but you will need an internet connection for the first download.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest creating a local nexus repository. This video is a good tutorial:

https://blog.sonatype.com/how-to-use-nexus-repository-with-maven-deploy-video